# Keep Animation Playing As ViewController is Dismissed?

Tags: ios, caanimation

I have a `CAKeyframeAnimation` that I want to keep playing as I swipe my finger from the left side of the screen (the swipe-back gesture in iOS 7).  Currently, it jumps to its startPosition as I swipe back and it stays static, and it looks rather sloppy.

The `ViewController` is a `detailViewController` that I have pushed from another `ViewController`.  Of course, I don't want the animation to play after I've dismissed the `detailViewController` in the background.  Just ***while it is being dismissed.***

This is my animation:

```
CGPoint startPoint = (CGPoint){160.f, 160.f};
CGPoint endPoint = (CGPoint){160.f, 15.f};

CGMutablePathRef thePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(thePath, NULL, startPoint.x, startPoint.y);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(thePath, NULL, endPoint.x, endPoint.y);

CAKeyframeAnimation *animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
animation.duration = 20.f;
animation.path = thePath;
animation.autoreverses = YES;
animation.repeatCount = INFINITY;
[self.myButton.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"position"];
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

EDIT with mode details: I have a UIView on top of a TableView (I'm not using Storyboards by the way).  Inside this UIView is a UIButton that moves up and down.  The UIView therefore acts as a sort of 'window' into seeing the UIButton move up and down.  As I swipe back, and as the detailViewController moves rightwards, I would like the UIButton to continue animating as it would.  (By on top of a tableView, I mean that it is positioned above a tableView.  It is not layered on top of it).

Comment: Can you describe the effect you're trying to accomplish?  If you're simply trying to get a UIView to slide across the screen, you're doing this the hardest way possible.

Comment: I have a UIView on top of a TableView (I'm not using Storyboards by the way).  Inside this UIView is a UIButton that moves up and down.  The UIView therefore acts as a sort of 'window' into seeing the UIButton move up and down.  As I swipe back, and as the detailViewController moves rightwards, I would like the UIButton to continue animating as it would.

Comment: (By on top of a tableView, I mean that it is positioned above a tableView.  It is not layered on top of it).

Comment: Are you looking for the "animation" to move in sync with the dismiss transition and/ or is the transition interactive?

Comment: It's not in sync with the dismissal at all - in fact, the 'dismissal' is just a regular swipe-back gesture in most iOS 7 apps.  All I'd like is for the animation to keep going until the detailViewController is completely out-of-sight :) Hopefully it isn't too difficult to do?

Comment: Sure, but swiping from the left screen edge on a UINavigationController's topViewController triggers an *interactive* transition (it remains in sync with the swipe gesture, and can be cancelled by returning your finger to the left screen edge). Do you want your animation to be in sync with the transition progress, or do you just want it to run it's course regardless of what the user does?

Comment: Oh thanks for clearing that up.  I would like it to run its course regardless of what the user does :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CAAnimations only update your button's presentation layer, not it's real position. I'm not aware of any way to ask them continue to during the navigation controller's pop transition.

Instead, I'd use an `NSTimer` or `CADisplayLink` to animate the actual button position. A simplistic example:

```
// in MyViewController.m

static CGFloat kButtonSpeed = 0.2f;
static CGFloat kButtonMinY = 15.f;
static CGFloat kButtonMaxY = 160.f;

- (void)initiateButtonAnimation
{
    if (_displayLink) {
        return;
    }

    _displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(moveButton)];
    [_displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
}

- (void)moveButton
{
    if (_frameTimestamp == 0) {
        _frameTimestamp = [_displayLink timestamp];
        return;
    }

    if (!_renderFrame) {
        _renderFrame = !_renderFrame;
        return;
    }

    double currentTime = [_displayLink timestamp];
    double renderTime = currentTime - _frameTimestamp;
    _frameTimestamp = currentTime;
    CGFloat amount = renderTime * 60.f * kButtonSpeed;

    CGFloat y = self.myButton.center.y;

    if (!_moveButtonDown && y > kButtonMinY) {
        y = y - amount;
    }
    else if (_moveButtonDown && y < kButtonMaxY)
        y = y + amount;
    else
        _moveButtonDown = !_moveButtonDown;

    self.myButton.center = CGPointMake(self.myButton.center.x, y);
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];

    // don't forget to invalidate & release
    [_displayLink invalidate];
    _displayLink = nil;
}
```

Comment: In my .h, I put: "@interface albumDetailViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
{
    CADisplayLink *displayLink;
    BOOL moveButtonDown;
}"

and then I copied your code (and removed the _ for displayLink) but it does not work.  What did I do wrong?  Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure - this code works for me with those ivars declared in a class extension. Where are you calling `-initiateButtonAnimation` from? Have you correctly set the initial position of myButton before doing so?

Comment: Oh no I fixed it, a silly mistake on my part.  One last thing - how do I change how quickly it goes?  Right now it moves quite fast.  Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I've amended the code to show how you might tweak the movement speed. If it works for you please mark the answer as accepted. I'd also recommend familiarising yourself with the general concepts of animating objects using CADisplayLink and NSRunLoop. Any good book on iOS Game Development or Core Animation should cover this.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but now it moves a stutters in a weird way - if it's moving upwards, it moves only a few pixels, stops, then continues to move upwards, and repeats.

Comment: In my .h, I have     `CADisplayLink *displayLink;
    int frameTimestamp;
    BOOL moveButtonDown;
    BOOL renderFrame;` - I don't know what's wrong?

Comment: Not sure - the code example works well enough for me: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/r9csgx8u4wlq0ed/AAAmerf5MUuoaxlMyK3Hs6HJa

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, it now works!  I had to move the declarations under @implementation in my .m which is strange.  I'll look into it some more.  I really appreciate your help!  :)

Answer (score 1):

```
UIButton* button = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160, 0, 320, 540)];
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{
    button.frame = CGRectMake(160, 10, 320, 540);
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    // nothing to see here
}];
```

This is probably the simplest way to accomplish the animation.  You might have to fiddle with different animation options, but this is the gist of what you want.

Comment: This makes the button move left, then right, then jump to a single position.  Also, when I swiped back during its short animation, it stopped just as before.  How do I make it loop and keep running as I swipe back?